# Adding links to POST/PUT/PATCH operations in REST Web Controllers

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I have a Java-written Web API wherein I have web controllers handling HTTP requests. I'm trying to implement a RESTful architecture with HATEOAS, using Spring Boot. When adding HATEOAS links in methods I can easily add links for GET/DELETE requests, but I'm having trouble with POST/PUT/PATCH requests, mostly because those require me to supply a body of the thing I want to post, usually in JSON format. I've been googling for a while and I can't find out how to do it.

Here's how I'm adding links to GET / DELETE operations.

```java
    /**
     * Shows all the Rooms present in the database.
     *
     * @return OK status and a list of Room Minimal DTO.
     */
    @GetMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getRooms() {
        List<RoomDTOMinimal> roomDTOList = roomRepository.getAllDTOWebInformation();
        for (RoomDTOMinimal r : roomDTOList) {
            if (userService.getUsernameFromToken().equals("ADMIN")) {
                Link roomSensors = linkTo(methodOn(RoomsWebController.class).getSensors(r.getName())).withRel("Get Room" +
                        "Sensors");
                Link deleteRoom = linkTo(methodOn(RoomsWebController.class).deleteRoom(r)).withRel("Delete this Room");
                r.add(roomSensors);
                r.add(deleteRoom);
            } else if (userService.getUsernameFromToken().equals("REGULAR_USER")) {
                Link roomTemp = linkTo(methodOn(RoomsWebController.class).getCurrentRoomTemperature(r.getName())).
                        withRel("Get Room Temperature");
                r.add(roomTemp);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(roomDTOList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I want to add a Link to an "editRoom" request, something like:

```java
                Link editRoom = linkTo(methodOn(RoomsWebController.class).configureRoom(r.getName(),  WHAT GOES HERE???).withSelfRel();
```

But configureRoom takes in the roomName and a roomDTO in its signature. RoomDTO is a @RequestBody, so I can't give it to the Link. How should I add the link to the objects in a way that then allows me to call on that method?

I'd like to have something like:

ROOM | Delete | Edit

On the client side, where if I click DELETE the room is deleted, and if I click Edit the client side expands, with text boxes, allowing me to insert the required parameters to edit the room. I have the client-side code implemented for the Edit function, with appropriate front-end; but I can't link to it on the server-side without already providing data that should come later, from the user input. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You should use `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I've since solved it after talking with a team lead. Apparently it's acceptable to either pass *null* or an empty DTO object as a parameter in the scenario above; the HATEOAS implementation cares specifically about those parameters that are of the path, and roughly speaking ignores the others. Those can then be replaced as needed on the client-side upon a user performing an action / inserting input.